# How to create deep-link for a specified content in my app with no associated website?

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am developing an android app.

I have a 'share' button with each photo and text in the app and what I want is I want a deep-link to be generated every time this 'share' button is clicked and the generated deep-link should get shared with anyone, doing it's job (opening the photo and text if app is installed and opening app in play store if app is not installed).

**What I want? (more clearly):** When the user clicks the 'share' button, a deep-link should get generated (this deep-link has the path to the photo and text). This deep-link could be shared with friends and when any of the friends open this deep-link he/she will be redirected to the photo and image path to which was stored in the  deep-link and if app is not installed, then this deep-link would open play store for user to download the app. I hope this will make my point more clear!

I searched google to achieve this and found [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app) link, but here they say (or means) that I require a website in order to generate deep-links.

Now, I don't have a website yet. What options are available for me? Or should I need a website first for achieving this?

Please let me know.

Comment: What you want to achieve exactly? Like searching for a product in mobile browser and found it, if the product have the app to open then it will open in app directly to the product page, or else it will open play store to install it. Do u want the same thing?

Comment: @Brendon please have a look at  updated question

Comment: of course you need a website to trigger the deep link with your app, why this so mean, the content which is available in a website is more optimized in a application, since then deep link to a particular content is achieved via linking the page to app, or at least opening the app is achieved without page linking. I hope you understand.

Comment: @brendon thanks for replying. I have a domain, but the website isn't ready. Can I use this domain somehow? How? Please elaborate.

Comment: Is the website published?

Comment: @brendon there is no website, just a domain name. Yes, the domain name is registered and live.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116042/discussion-between-brendon-and-hammad-nasir).

Comment: What you're describing is exactly what [Firebase Invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android) and [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android) do. You create a dynamic link and then send that in an invite. You don't *need* a web site. If you're having trouble getting them to work, show what you've tried.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks a lot for replying. I have successfully created dynamic link, but having problem here with using it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123493/how-to-show-specific-content-in-my-app-upon-clicking-on-a-deep-link# 
Please do have a look!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen did you have a look on my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123493/how-to-show-specific-content-in-my-app-upon-clicking-on-a-deep-link# It is related to `dynamic-links`. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have website and want to share content between your Apps (iOS or Android) you can use solution like Firebase Dynamic Links https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Firebase Dynamic Links will handle Universal Links/App Links for you using their own website.

You need to create dynamic link. As a payload, you providing any valid link, like https://example.com/?my_urlencoded_key=my_url_encoded_value&my_urlencoded_key1=my_url_encoded_value1

Check out documentation for parameters and options Firebase Dynamic Links provides https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links

If such link is tapped on iOS the link will be handled in your App. If App is not installed the link will forward user to AppStore. After App first launch you will get pending dynamic link.

If such link is tapped on Android the link will be handled in your App. If App is not installed the link will forward user to AppStore. After App first launch you will get pending dynamic link.

In your case you are getting into weird situation when link clicked on desktop. In this case user will be navigated to payload, in this case https://example.com/?.... You can improve this by specifying parameter "dfl" - desktop fallback link (not exposed in client libraries yet) https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener
As dfl you can provide your company website.

Comment: I can see "ofl" in the docs (for "other" platforms), not "dfl".